# how can I add a hover state to inputs?

Tags: html, css

```
input[type="email"]:hover {
    border-color: #848484;
}

input[type="email"]:active {
    border-color: #0174DF;
}

input[type="email"]:focus {
    border-color: #0174DF;
}
```

I want to make an `input` like the one on Google search, when the cursor is over input (not focus) the color of border gets dark (I've made this with `:hover`), when I click on the Input now change to blue, but just when I release the click the color get backs to the  `:hover` state, how can I do that?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/eV8ru/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
input[type="email"] {
    outline: none;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid #A4A4A4;

}

input[type="email"]:hover {
    border-color: #939393;
}   

input[type="email"]:focus {
    border-color: #0080FF;
}
```

to have the same input at google.com